# Resizing divs and aligning background

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

```
<div style="width: 600px;">  
    <div class="header">
    <img src="logo.png"/>
</div>


<div class="container">
    <div class="div1">Div 1</div>
    <div class="div2">Div 2</div>
    <div class="div3">Div 3</div>
    <div class="div4">Div 4</div>
    <div class="div5">Div 5</div>
</div>


.header
{
    height:200px;
    background-image: url('http://www.imgur.com/YLVpI.png');
    margin:0;
    width:100%;
    background-position:left;  
}
.header img
{
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}
.container .div1
{
    background-color: black;
    background-position:left;  
    float:left;
    width:20%;
    margin: 0px;

}
.container .div2
{
    background-image: url('http://www.imgur.com/YLVpI.png');
    background-position:left;  
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    margin:0; padding:0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}
.container .div3
{
    background-image: url('http://www.imgur.com/YLVpI.png');
    background-position:left;  
    float:left;
    margin:0; padding:0;
}
.container .div4
{
    background-image: url('http://www.imgur.com/YLVpI.png');
    background-position:left;  
    float:left;
    width:100px;
    margin:0; padding:0;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}
.container .div5
{
    background-color: black;
    float:left;
    display:inline-block; width:90px;
    width:20%;
    margin:0;
}
```

There are several things I cannot get to work simultaneously:

1. Make the header span 100% of the page width.
2. Make div 2 and 4 a set width of 30px each.
3. Make div 3 a set width of 400px.
4. Make div 1 and 5 fill the remaining space regardless of how big the window is.
5. Center everything so it looks nice.
6. Make the background align correctly.

Does anyone know how to do this? http://jsfiddle.net/jaTuu/

Comment: Actually whole thing you are doing is wrong, you should `float` your div's instead of making it `inline`, secondly, your `header background` is not 100% cuz container div is just `600px wide` so make it `100%;`

Comment: can you post the image of your desired result...........

Comment: Ah I see - had an extra div at the start messing things up :/

Comment: @idb you like this want http://tinkerbin.com/pdF55X4v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you solved 5 on your own, and as far as I know, without extraneous stuff, you need Javascript to do number 4. I cannot attempt 6 without access to your images. Nevertheless, I think you can resolve that on your own.

Below is the solution I came up with given your code:

```
<div id="header_container" style="width: 600px;">

    <div class="header">
    <img src="logo.png"/>
</div>


<div class="container"><div class="div1">Div 1</div><div class="div2 width30">Div 2</div><div class="div3 width300">Div 3</div><div class="div4 width30">Div 4</div><div class="div5">Div 5</div>
</div> 
*
{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

#header_container {
    background-color: #000;
    min-width: 100%;
}

.width30 {
    width: 30px;
}

.width300 {
    width: 300px;
}

.header
{
    height:200px; 
    background-image: url('http://www.imgur.com/YLVpI.png'); 
    margin:0;
    background-position:left;  
}
.header img
{
    margin-left:auto; 
    margin-right:auto;
}
.container
{
    text-align:center;
}
.container .div1
{
    background-image: url('http://www.imgur.com/YLVpI.png');
    background-position:left;  
    display:inline-block; 
    background-color: yellow;
    width:90px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 20px;
}
.container .div2
{
    background-image: url('http://www.imgur.com/YLVpI.png');
    background-position:left;  
    background-color: purple;
    display:inline-block; 
    /*width:90px;*/
    margin:0; padding:0;
}
.container .div3
{
    background-image: url('http://www.imgur.com/YLVpI.png');
    background-position:left; 
    background-color: green;    
    display:inline-block; 
    /*width:90px;*/
}
.container .div4
{
    background-image: url('http://www.imgur.com/YLVpI.png');
    background-position:left; 
    background-color: blue;    
    display:inline-block; 
    /*width:90px;*/

}
.container .div5
{
    background-image: url('http://www.imgur.com/YLVpI.png');
    background-position:left;
    background-color: orange;    
    display:inline-block; 
    width:90px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 20px;
}
```

A couple things to note here:

Assuming that you want the element names to remain distinct, you can modify the width of the items by adding classes which define sizes as per the above. If you do so, as I did, you will have to remove the widths of the elements as you define them in the CSS (also shown above).

One more note: it seems as though you are attempting to do a navigation menu. If that is the case, it may be a better idea to use lists to represent the items.

Answer (score 0):

Try to centering all background images.

```
background: url('http://www.imgur.com/YLVpI.png') center center;
```

Like this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ongisnade/PThcc/